# ASP.NET & IIS7 : losing access rights all of a sudden 

Tags: asp.net, security, iis-7, permissions, acl

I'm working locally on an ASP.NET website under Windows 7, and I experience stange behaviours sometimes ...

I've been working several days with several Visual Studio opened, working on the website, then I switched to compiling and deploying some others apps until yesterday, and today, I had to get back working on the website. 
So I launched a browser and entered the url "//localhost/" as usual ...

Unexpectedly, IIS tells me :

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server
>   Error
>
> Error Code    0x80070005
>
> Config Error  Cannot read configuration
>   file due to insufficient permissions
>
> Config
>   File  \?\C:\DVP-WP\SQ2sln_web\web.config

Well, 2 days ago, web.config was accessed without trouble !
**What happened**? Of cours, I cannot remember having changed *anything* regarding ACL or accounts or .. just writing c# code and asp.net and compiling !!!

Why does this happen ?

STEP2: So I went to the folder where the website files are located and applied some security:
I specify **machine\IIS_IUSR** to have read access to the folder website folder ("SQ2sln_web")
... OK , II7 now servers the aspx pages I request at the root level ... but **not the css file**!

> HTTP Error 401.3 - Unauthorized
>
> Requested URL
>   [...] localhost:80/soquiz.css
>
> Physical Path
>   C:\DVP-WP\SQ2sln_web\soquiz.css
>
> Logon Method Anonymous
>
> Logon User Anonymous

So I set some **specific rights** to the file itself (see picture at *http://soquiz.com/resources/documents/acl%20problem%20file%20specific.gif*)

... but it did not solve the problem

1) Does anyone know WHY or HOW access rights change ?

2) Does anyone know why setting specific acl to one file do not work ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to check the account that your application pool is running under as well.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it is  "ApplicationPoolId" (which I don't fully understand)
Anyway, why would access right change all of a sudden ?

Comment: I am not sure what changed, but something did, if it was working before.  The application pool account is just one more place to check.  I was thinking that maybe you moved your virtual directory, or recreated it from source control.  If you move your project under c:\inetput\wwwroot, I will bet that you don't have any problems either.  Compare the security on everything if it was in wwwroot versus your current directory.

Comment: Thank you Richard, you gave me a nice piece of advice. I think I can guess what changed (without me intenting to change anything): TFS SOURCE CONTROL ! That's well possible that I asked for a "Get Latest Version" "with overwrite" which involved several projects ... that seems a good explanation.
As for having the websiteS under "c:\inetput\wwwroot", I did not know that it would solve such issues, but it makes sense !!